# Remove All Rows with Unique Id If Another Column has specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to remove **ALL** instances of PaymentId If Label is "Error".

```
CREATE TABLE Test
(Id INT, PaymentId INT, Label VARCHAR(25));

INSERT INTO Test
VALUES
(1, 22, 'Error'),
(2, 22, 'Seattle'),
(3, 22, 'Pending'),
(4, 33, 'Paid'),
(5, 33, 'Los Angeles'),
(6, 44, 'Houston'),
(7, 44, 'Error'),
(8, 55, 'Pending'),
(9, 55, 'San Diego'),
(10, 55, 'Authorization')

SELECT * FROM Test
```

| Id | PaymentId | Label |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **22** | **Error** |
| 2 | **22** | Seattle |
| 3 | **22** | Pending |
| 4 | 33 | Paid |
| 5 | 33 | Los Angeles |
| 6 | **44** | Houston |
| 7 | **44** | **Error** |
| 8 | 55 | Pending |
| 9 | 55 | San Diego |
| 9 | 55 | Authorization |

Expected Output:

| Id | PaymentId | Label |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 33 | Paid |
| 5 | 33 | Los Angeles |
| 8 | 55 | Pending |
| 9 | 55 | San Diego |
| 9 | 55 | Seattle |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just another option via a CTE and the window function `sum() over()`

```
;with cte as (
SELECT * 
      ,Flg = sum( case when Label='Error' then 1 end) over (partition by PaymentID)
 FROM Test
)
Delete from cte where Flg >=1
```

**The Updated Table**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use IN.

```
delete from Test
where PaymentId in  (select PaymentId from test where Label='Error' );
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6a679e5b17f247311a6fefbbc738fd6f)